# Show SMS content only after unlock? (Handcent)

Tags: lock-screens, privacy, handcent-sms

Is there a way to make Handcent show an SMS only after the screen is unlocked? Right now it shows the whole message in some kind of preview even when the screen is locked. Browsed the options a few times but didn't find a solution.. Is there such an option, or did I just miss it?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will find it in Settings > Notification Settings > then make sure Enable Popup is not selected. (*I just tested disabling Popup messages - it works. Phone vibrates with new message, screen stays off.*)

Alternatively, you can keep Popup enabled, select Popup Settings > then make sure Screen on for popup is not selected. This should allow the Popup when you're using the phone, but not when the screen is off.